# How to access form data as an array of a JSON object in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

I have jQuery Ajax sending form data to a WordPress function.

The PHP function gets the data as a string, like "navn=A&navn2=B", and I use the explode() function to access individual form elements.

I think there is a better way where I can access the form data as an array of JSON objects directly. But I can't figure that out.

How can I fix it?

This is my HTML/jQuery:

```
<form id='minForm' method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="navn" value="A">
  <input type="text" name="navn2" value="B">
  <button>Send</button>
</form>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var form = $('#minForm');
    $(form).submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var formData = $(form).serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {
          action     : 'my_ajax_action',
          formData   : formData,
        },
        success:function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is my PHP:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_ajax_action', 'my_ajax_action_callback');

function my_ajax_action_callback() {
  $form_data = $_POST['formData'];
  $form_data_array = explode('&', $form_data);

  foreach ($form_data_array as $i) {
    echo explode('=', $i)[1] . '<BR>';
  }
  wp_die(); // Required. to end Ajax request.
}
```

Comment: `parse_str` function

Comment: Thanks, nice function. Not sure thou if I should prefer this solution over the other answer. BR

Answer (score 1):

Serialize your form as an array. Then pass it in the Ajax request.

In the client side:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      var form = $('#minForm');
      $(form).submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(form).serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
            action     : 'my_ajax_action',
            formData   : formData,
          },
          success:function(data) {
            console.log(data);
          },
        });
      });
    });
```

On the server side:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_ajax_action', 'my_ajax_action_callback');

function my_ajax_action_callback() {
  $response = ["success" => true];
  $form_data = json_decode($_POST['formData']);
  error_log(print_r($form_data, 1)); // Log to see the array properties.
  if (empty($form_data) {
      $response["success"]  = false;
  }
  echo json_encode($response);
  //wp_die(); // required. to end AJAX request.
}
```

Note: The `$(form).serializeArray()` will give you the form as an **array** of **objects**, and it might not be what you expect in the server side to extract data. You can handle the **form array** before sending to the server by convert it to a simple **object**:

```
var formData = $(form).serializeArray().reduce(function(obj,item){
     obj[item.key] = item.value;
     return obj;
}, {});
```

Comment: Why do you comment out wp_die()?
I'm right, that this is either gonna return true or false and not any data?
It returns false. Why could that be?

Comment: @Kresten I commented because what matters in your response is the echo on the json object. If you need it you can use it. On a normal situation you wouldn’t need any die to respond to the client as long as you don’t echo something else on the process